# Why would a UIAlert cause one of my other variables to be nil?

Tags: ios, swift, null, uilabel, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to make a UIAlert pop up, but whenever the code calls the function that should do that, a value totally unrelated in the process caused an error saying that it returned nil when it expected to have a value. I solved the issue, but I have no idea why my solution worked.

The original:

```
var fullFreqHeard: [Double] = []

@IBOutlet weak var fullFreqLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fullFreqLabel.text = "\(fullFreqHeard)"
}
```

The solution:

```
var fullFreqHeard: [Double] = []

@IBOutlet weak var fullFreqLabel: UILabel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fullFreqLabel?.text = "\(fullFreqHeard)"
}
```

The difference is in the original I force unwrapped the label, whereas in the solution I used a '?'. What is going on here? I was also wondering if it might have anything to do with the alert.

Comment: Do you actually see the label when you run it?  It might not be hooked up correctly.

Comment: Yea I see the label

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with the alert. The reason force unwrapping fixes the error is because fullFreqLabel is initially nil. You have to initialize it before setting it's value. For instance, `var fullFreqLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)`

Comment: I used storyboards and I put that label in with storyboards. Wouldn't that make it not nil?